# Disable Seeking in VideoView Control Android

Tags: android

I am developing an app where I am playing live channels , so i dont need to seek and requirement is to disable seeking in my videoview. I can not find any property in video View control that can make seeking disable. Does any one know how I can do so?

I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: You can disable control of videoview , not only Seeking !

Comment: Thanks, Nirav Ranpara. could you please tell me How to disable controls of VideoView?

Comment: But in that case i will disable user from video pause and play as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hiding the Controls in the VideoView, set null to MediaController property.

The Code snippet is as below :

```
videoView.setMediaController(null)
```

Comment: this is okay with videoview removing controller but in this case i can not even pause video, can u plz tell me how to set some customized controller to videoview??

Comment: No No. android sdk do not provide customized controller for videoview

Comment: So is there no way around to do this?

Comment: you can customize MediaPlayer in android not videoview.